# How to combine two onClick for change text of Button and play/stop sound

Tags: java, android

How to combine two functions in one button?
How to make when button clicked - the button text change and sound will play

Now I can only play the sound or just change the button text

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button one;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);

        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String ButtonText=one.getText().toString();

                if(ButtonText.equals("Stop")){
                    one.setText("Play");

                }else {
                    one.setText("Stop");

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're already changing the button text in your `onClick` event handler. If you're using some method call to play the desired sound, you can just put that in your `onClick` handler method as well. Eg:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String ButtonText=one.getText().toString();
    // method call that plays the sound
    if(ButtonText.equals("Stop")){
        one.setText("Play");
    } else {
        one.setText("Stop");
    }
}
```